# NGRX - How do I fix "Errors were found in your package-lock.json"?

Tags: angular, npm, ngrx, package.json

I am using Angular in NX workspace with NGRX and want to build it in Jenkins but I am getting errors after running `npm install`.

Anyone see errors like this after running:
`nx update` && then `npm run audit`  ??

```
npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's @ngrx/schematics@10.1.0 does not satisfy @ngrx/schematics@10.0.0
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's @ngrx/store-devtools@10.1.0 does not satisfy @ngrx/store-devtools@10.0.0
```

The actual app works fine - using `nx serve`

I want to fix the errors so I can run my Jenkins job.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read, you’re having version differences between `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

Delete `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` again.

Comment: I already tried deleting node modules and the json files. It did not make any difference.

Comment: You are correct though. The problem was that the same module was loaded in both the dev dependecies and the normal dependecies and they had different versions.  I deleted the one not matching and ran npm install and it fixed the issue.  Thanks